# Online clicker that add number from different user simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html

Before explaining my problem I would like to specify that i'm new, I have never done anything like this before.
The idea is simple, I would like to make a simple page hosted in Altervista that when a button is pressed add +1 to a counter. The fact is that I would like to make this counter "online" for everyone, in the sense that if two different people from two different computers press the button simultaneously the counter add 2 and is visible to all.

An extra is to add a simple "insert your user name here" to let the website store your username and show how in percentage you contributed to the total number, but I repeat this is only an extra.

This is what I wrote for now, please don't judge my abilities.

```js
if (localstorage.clickcount) {
  document.getElementById("myNumber").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount;
}

function myFunction() {
  if (localStorage.clickcount) {
    localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
  } else {
    localStorage.clickcount = 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("myNumber").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount;

}
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 45px 75px;
  font-size: 72px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41
}

.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> CIAO GRIFONINJA</title>

</head>

<body>


  <h1 style="text-align: center;color: brown">SALUTA GRIFONINJA</h1>

  <button class="button" , onclick="myFunction()">CIAO GRIFONINJA</button>
  <p></p>
  Saluti: <span id=myNumber></span>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What you're attempting is non-trivial. The closest thing that might be considered an out-of-the-box solution is graphql subscription and mutation to update some persistent counter on a server. Your code only modifies the value in a single user's browser.

Comment: @AndrewGillis is tottaly right. You'll need more that a single HTML page to solve this.

Comment: I like to help new guys.
The function 'myfunction' runs on each visitor's browser and doesn't communicate with Altervista at all.
You need an online service that runs a service that will let you store and access data, as suggested above, or that will let you upload and run your own software .